# MySql percentil for MIN and MAX values

Tags: mysql, database, statistics

We have some charts, where we show an AVG value, alongs side with MAX() and MIN() values.

Because of the data they want to remove the 'extremes' for the MAX() and MIN() values.

So the request is for ore each record: instead of the plain MIN() show the MIN use the 5% percentil, and for the MAX() the 95% percentil.

id, parent_cat, id, attentionTime

so far the queries were simple, something like:

```
select AVG(attentionTime) AS time_attention, 
    MAX(attentionTime) AS time_max, 
    MIN(attentionTime) AS time_min 
FROM records_stats 
WHERE parent_cat = {N}
```

I'm not a maths dude, so any help trying to understand the problem is appreciated.

percentil, in Database terms is like: removing the values where the AVG is less than 5? or remove the ones over 95?

Comment: If you're not a maths dude, may I suggest that you're in the wrong line of work! Anyway, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If I understand what you are tasked to do, you need to get the average attentionTime after excluding rows that are 5% above the minimum and rows that are 5% below the maximum. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-queries to get the overall min/max values, and then in the where clause use between to get the average of the intended rows.

The percentile values would be a percentage of the *range* vs the min/max values. The query below applies the percentages to the range, then scales it back to the values by adding the minimum value.

For example, if the min value is 100 and the max value is 1000, the range is 900. 5% of 900 is 45, and 95% is 855, so you want the average of rows with values between 45 and 855.

```
select AVG(attentionTime) AS time_attention, 
    (SELECT ((MAX(attentionTime) - MIN(attentionTime)) * 0.95) + MIN(attentionTime) FROM records_stats WHERE parent_cat = {N}) AS time_max, 
    (SELECT ((MAX(attentionTime) - MIN(attentionTime)) * 0.05) + MIN(attentionTime) FROM records_stats WHERE parent_cat = {N}) AS time_min
FROM records_stats 
WHERE parent_cat = {N}
    AND attentionTime BETWEEN time_min AND time_max
```

Comment: Im not sure if the query is exactly what i want, but your example with numbers has helped me understand and is finally starting to make sense.Im heading home to smash my head again with this issue and try it with some data. Thanks for your answer